# Efficient way to get the non null string values from two pandas series aligned with index

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, nan

I have two pandas string series with `nan` as well, lets say:

```
a = pd.Series(['A', 'B', np.nan, np.nan])
b = pd.Series(['A', np.nan, 'C', np.nan])
```

and the output required as follows:

```
result = ['A', 'B', 'C', np.nan]
```

What could be most efficient and pythonic way to get the desired result. Please note that my series comprises of 1 million entries so most efficient way (probably usage of `numpy`) is also acceptable.

Comment: What happens if both have values and are not the same?

Comment: `a.combine_first(b)`? Though as the name suggests, that takes non-null results from `a` before `b`.

Comment: @RockyLi No.. This is I know is not possible for a problem I am working on.

Comment: The order is important?

Comment: @anishtain4 Yes, the order is important,

Comment: The `combine_first` works well for me, can you elaborate why it's not possible for your problem?

Comment: Thanks guys, `combine_first` worked for me as well. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `fillna`.

```
a.fillna(b)

0      A
1      B
2      C
3    NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(pd.DataFrame([a,b]).apply(lambda x: next(iter(x.dropna().tolist()),np.nan),axis=0))
```

Better is `conbine_first`:

```
print(a.combine_first(b))
```

Both Output:

```
0      A
1      B
2      C
3    NaN
dtype: object
```